# regex python apagar tudo depois da segunda ocorrência de um whitespace

Tags: python, regex

Isso deve ser muito simples e eu não consigo encontrar uma resposta. Eu tenho diversas strings de tamanhos diferentes que têm mais ou menos o mesmo padrão:

`'Art. 1° E'` 
`'Art. 15. As'`

O que eu quero fazer é apagar tudo depois da segunda ocorrência do whitespace, ficando com os resultados `'Art. 1°'` e `'Art. 15.'`

```
teste = "Art. 1° E"

print(re.sub(r'((.*?){2})', '', teste))
#Art.
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar com a regex?

Comment: Veja se serve: `print(re.findall(r'Art.\s\S+', teste))` .No caso eu testei usando a constituição e aparentemente retorna o que precisa. Se funcionar avise que coloco como resposta depois do almoço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta fazer:

```
print(re.sub(r' [^ ]+$', '', teste))
```

A regex tem um espaço (repare que há um espaço após a `'`), seguido de um ou mais caracteres que não são espaço (`[^ ]+`), e o final da string (`$`). Isso garante que eu pego do último espaço até o final da string.

Mas isso funciona apenas para o caso do segundo espaço ser o último. Se a ideia é ignorar do segundo espaço em diante, talvez seja melhor fazer uma regex que pegue o trecho inicial e ignore o resto:

```
import re
teste = "Art. 1° E abc xyz"
match = re.match(r'^Art\. \d+[.°]', teste)
if match:
    print(match.group(0)) # Art. 1°
```

Ou seja, eu busco por "Art. " no início da string (indicado por `^`), seguido de um ou mais dígitos (`\d+`), seguido de um ponto ou o caractere `°` (indicado por `[.°]`). Se for encontrado, eu pego somente este trecho.

---

Outra alternativa é não usar regex:

```
print(teste[0:teste.rfind(' ')])
```

`rfind` encontra a posição da última ocorrência do espaço. Então eu uso a sintaxe de *slicing* para pegar tudo do início da string (a posição zero) até a posição do último espaço.

Comment: Muito obrigada!!